# Trying to set up Java DB: "Class Not Found: JDBC driver org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver could not be loaded"

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ant

I'm completely new to SQL, and I'm trying to set up a database to practice using it.

I'm on Windows 7.

I'm following Oracle's JDBC Basics tutorial (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/gettingstarted.html#step1) and have so far:

1. Installed JDK (they say to install Java SE SDK, but as far as I can tell, JDK and Java SE SDK are more or less the same?)
2. Installed Apache Ant.
3. Downloaded the sample code.
4. Modified the build.xml.
5. Modified the tutorial properties files.
6. Gone into Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System... -> Environment Variables and added PATH (C:\Program\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin;%ANT_HOME%/bin;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32).
7. I go to cmd, change directory and run ant jar. It complies successfully.
8. I run ant setup (which is supposed to create the database), and I get this error message:

> Buildfile: C:\Program\Java\JDBCTutorial\build.xml
>
> setup:
>
> drop-tables:
>
> BUILD FAILED C:\Program\Java\JDBCTutorial\build.xml:140: The following
>   error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Program\Java\JDBCTutorial\build.xml:83: Class Not Found: JDBC
>   driver org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver could not be loaded
>
> Total time: 0 seconds

I don't know if I have the JDBC drivers - the tutorial says they're included in the download, but I don't know where to look for them to verify. I'm also thinking there might be something wrong with the PATH variable. I've also seen people mention there could be problems with the classpath, but I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Can you post build.xml line 83?

Comment: delimiter="${DB.DELIMITER}" autocommit="false" onerror="continue">

Comment: Line 80 - 84:

<target name="drop-tables">
    <sql driver="${DB.DRIVER}" url="${DB.URL}" userid="${DB.USER}"
         password="${DB.PASSWORD}" classpathref="CLASSPATH"
         delimiter="${DB.DELIMITER}" autocommit="false" onerror="continue">
      <transaction src="./sql/${DB.VENDOR}/drop-tables.sql"></transaction>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to add the missing lib. You can download it here http://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html Then configure `JAVADBDRIVER`to point to the jar file.

> JAVADBDRIVER The full path name of your Java DB driver. This is
>   typically /lib/derby.jar.